# How to correctly use StreamingRecognizeRequest from http audio stream

Tags: java, google-api, speech-recognition, audio-streaming, google-speech-api

Why am I not getting any responses back (from StreamingRecognizeRequests) in my responseObserver.onResponse() method below?

Stuck as to how to proceed further on this one.

**Code (which is simplified to highlight the issue as a modification to the google sample code)**

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-speech</artifactId>
  <version>0.72.0-beta</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jflac</groupId>
  <artifactId>jflac-codec</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

---

```
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientStream;
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.ResponseObserver;
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.StreamController;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.*;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import org.jflac.sound.spi.FlacAudioFileReader;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

---

```
public static void streamingUrlRecognize(String url) {

ResponseObserver<StreamingRecognizeResponse> responseObserver = null;
try (SpeechClient client = SpeechClient.create()) {

  responseObserver =
      new ResponseObserver<StreamingRecognizeResponse>() {
        ArrayList<StreamingRecognizeResponse> responses = new ArrayList<>();

        public void onStart(StreamController controller) {}

        public void onResponse(StreamingRecognizeResponse response) {

          responses.add(response);
        }

        public void onComplete() {
          for (StreamingRecognizeResponse response : responses) {
            StreamingRecognitionResult result = response.getResultsList().get(0);
            SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
            System.out.printf("Transcript : %s\n", alternative.getTranscript());
          }
        }

        public void onError(Throwable t) {
          System.out.println(t);
        }
      };

  ClientStream<StreamingRecognizeRequest> clientStream =
      client.streamingRecognizeCallable().splitCall(responseObserver);

  RecognitionConfig recognitionConfig =
      RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
          .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
          .setLanguageCode("en-US")
          .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
          .build();

  StreamingRecognitionConfig streamingRecognitionConfig =
      StreamingRecognitionConfig.newBuilder().setConfig(recognitionConfig).build();

  StreamingRecognizeRequest request =
      StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
          .setStreamingConfig(streamingRecognitionConfig)
          .build(); // The first request in a streaming call has to be a config

  FlacAudioFileReader mp= new FlacAudioFileReader();
  AudioInputStream in=mp.getAudioInputStream(new URL(url));
  AudioFormat targetFormat = new AudioFormat(16000, 16, 1, true, false);
  AudioInputStream audioInputStream=AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(targetFormat, in);

  clientStream.send(request);

  long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

  while (true) {
    long estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    byte[] data = new byte[6400];
    audioInputStream.read(data);
    if (estimatedTime > 10000) { // 60 seconds
      break;
    }
    request =
        StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
            .setAudioContent(ByteString.copyFrom(data))
            .build();
    clientStream.send(request);
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}
responseObserver.onComplete();
}
```

---

I've been able to confirm that its not an audio format issue.  When I write the buffers out into a ByteArrayOutputStream(baos) for a set period of time (eg 10 seconds), the inputs are recognized and I get responses back as expected.

```
RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
    .setContent(ByteString.copyFrom(baos.toByteArray()))
    .build();

RecognizeResponse response = client.recognize(recognitionConfig, audio);
List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.getResultsList();
```

**Background**

Goal here is to write a method which will listen to a (time unbounded) FLAK http audio stream and perform streaming speech recognition (using `StreamingRecognizeRequest` requests).  I'm using latest com.google.cloud.speech (0.72.0-beta).

Comment: What exactly is your question? Can you rephrase the title, to make it more clear?

Comment: apologies, bit of a case of "long time listener first time caller" here.  Ive restructured to make it clearer.  Basically the code snip attached is not getting responses from StreamingRecognizeRequest

Comment: Could you find a solution?